# Read from 1 file to produce 2 files

Tags: java

I've been trying to do this problem for my schoolwork and for the life of me I cannot figure it out. 
The problem is: Write a program that reads in "worked_example_1/babynames.txt" and produces two files, boynames.txt and girlnames.txt, separating the data for the boys and girls.

This is the code from Worked Example 11 from wiley.com/go/javaexamples for this problem:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BabyNames
{
public static final double LIMIT = 50;

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("babynames.txt"));

    RecordReader boys = new RecordReader(LIMIT);
    RecordReader girls = new RecordReader(LIMIT);

    while (boys.hasMore() || girls.hasMore())
    {
        int rank = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print(rank + " ");
        boys.process(in);
        girls.process(in);
        System.out.println();
    }

    in.close();
}
}
```

And this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RecordReader
{
private double total;
private double limit;

public RecordReader(double aLimit)
{
    total = 0;
    limit = aLimit;
}

public void process(Scanner in)
{
    String name = in.next();
    int count = in.nextInt();
    double percent = in.nextDouble();

    if (total < limit)
    {
        System.out.print(name + " ");
    }

    total = total + percent;
}

public boolean hasMore()
{
    return total < limit;
}
}
```

I created the babynames.txt and put in the same src folder as the .java file, it comes up with file not found, if I give the direct path to the file with

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/me/SkyDrive/Schoolwork/CIS150AB/Chapter 11.1/src/babynames.txt"));
```

it finds the file but gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at BabyNames.main(BabyNames.java:20)
```

To me it looks like this error is because of Line 20 where int rank = in.nextInt(); and its looking for a string when its looking for an int, but this is directly from Wiley website so I am not sure.

Any help with this would be appreciated, apparently I am not meant for online classes for Java. Next class I am taking in school once there is one that works around my schedule.

Comment: There may be wrong with the `babynames.txt` file. Can you provide it? Also, don't get discouraged from a small error like this. Simple I/O in Java can be a little difficult but you can get used to it with a little practice.

Comment: The problem is it asks to take the babynames info from the website, well the website has Big Java: Early Objects 5th Edition and it tells you to get the text file from the book. The book in my class is Java Concepts: Early Objects 7th edition. So I found a babynames.txt file online, the text file is supposed to have the most popular baby names and the ranking of the baby name. I will attach the file I found. https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=F544BAADAAC526E5!26857&authkey=!AMw7rMHPTO3T720

Comment: Your file is very large and slightly unwieldy to work with. A common technique in fixing bugs in your code is reducing your problem to something that you can diagnose easier and are more confident will work. So, try creating a new text file with just a few names and see how your code behaves then.

Comment: I truncated it to about 10 names with the numbers for rankings, and it still throws the
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at BabyNames.main(BabyNames.java:20)

Comment: Have you tried creating a breakpoint in your code at the line in question and examining the values in the variable/s? Instead of using in.nextInt() read in a string and look at its contents, then trim whitespace and parse as an int. What is probably happening is trailing or preceding whitespace is getting sucked in.

Comment: Did your problem get solved?

Answer (score 0):

If [this](https://bitbucket.org/cayhorstmann/pythonforeveryone/src/a7b2fe3930a9/ch07/babynames.txt) is the format of your babynames.txt, this is what'll happen (I think, didn't try it).

- The scanner "in" reads the first int into "rank" (OK)
- Enter into boys.process()

  - "in" reads the first name (Jacob)
  - "in" tries to read the first int (1), but finds 1.0013, which is not an int

This scenario doesn't match your error (you'd get a stacktrace from RecordReader rather than from BabyNames) but maybe the line of thinking will work for you.

Try it with a debugger. If you can't, use in.next() rather than in.nextInt() or in.nextDouble(). You can than print the value and see why it's not what you think it is.

Your question actually raises two questions. The answer to the hidden one may be:

```
try (InputStream inputStream = BabyNames.class.getResourceAsStream("/babynames.txt");
     Scanner in = new Scanner(inputStream))
{
    // do stuff with in
}
```